# AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, floating-point

I am trying to convert all the cells value (except date) to float point number, I can successfully convert first 3 column but getting an error on the last one:

Here is my code:

```
df['Market Cap_'+str(coin)] = df['Market Cap_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
df['Volume_'+str(coin)] = df['Volume_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
df['Open_'+str(coin)] = df['Open_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float) 
df['Close_'+str(coin)] = df['Close_'+str(coin)].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
```

Here is `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 30 entries, 1 to 30
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------               --------------  -----         
 0   Date_ETHEREUM        30 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   Market Cap_ETHEREUM  30 non-null     float64       
 2   Volume_ETHEREUM      30 non-null     float64       
 3   Open_ETHEREUM        30 non-null     float64       
 4   Close_ETHEREUM       30 non-null     object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 1.4+ KB
```

And here is the Error:

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

As you can see the column type is an object, (same as what others were before conversion, but I'm getting an error on this one)

Comment: there may be another extra character in that column that you are not replacing, like you do for ```,``` and ```$``` and so it's failing to convert it. Try finding out more about the data in that column

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error can means you have value different then string - ie integer value - and it can't use string function with this value